# Is there a C# equivalent to Java's CountDownLatch?

Tags: c#, multithreading, synchronization, countdownlatch

Is there a C# equivalent to Java's [CountDownLatch](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html?is-external=true)?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The .NET Framework version 4 includes the new [System.Threading.CountdownEvent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.countdownevent(VS.100).aspx) class.

Comment: I'm going to compare both answers and I might have to award it to you (CesarGon)... it seems that yours is better, because you offer a solution that is built into C# already.

Comment: That's fair enough, Lirik. :-)

Answer (score 19):

Here is a simple implementation (from [9 Reusable Parallel Data Structures and Algorithms](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163427.aspx#S1)):

> To build a countdown latch, you just
>   initialize its counter to n, and have
>   each subservient task atomically
>   decrement it by one when it finishes,
>   for example by surrounding the
>   decrement operation with a lock or
>   with a call to Interlocked.Decrement.
>   Then, instead of a take operation, a
>   thread could decrement and wait for
>   the counter to become zero; when
>   awoken, it will know that n signals
>   have been registered with the latch.
>   Instead of spinning on this condition,
>   as in while (count != 0), it’s usually
>   a good idea to let the waiting thread
>   block, in which case you then have to
>   use an event.
>
> ```
> public class CountdownLatch {
>     private int m_remain;
>     private EventWaitHandle m_event;
>
>     public CountdownLatch(int count) {
>         m_remain = count;
>         m_event = new ManualResetEvent(false);
>     }
>
>     public void Signal() {
>         // The last thread to signal also sets the event.
>         if (Interlocked.Decrement(ref m_remain) == 0)
>             m_event.Set();
>     }
>
>     public void Wait() {
>         m_event.WaitOne();
>     }
> }
> ```