# When All Threads Are Complete

Tags: c#, multithreading

This is my first real attempt at using multithreading, I want to know how I can tell when all of my tasks groups are done running:

```
for (int i = 0; i < taskGroups.Count(); i++) {
    ThreadStart t = delegate { RunThread(taskGroups[i]); };
    new Thread(t).Start();
}
if(allThreadsComplete){ //???

}
```

Any help would be much appreciated

Addendum:

```
ThreadStart[] threads = new ThreadStart[taskGroups.Count()];
for (int i = 0; i < taskGroups.Count(); i++) {
    threads[i] = new ThreadStart[]
    threads[i] = delegate { RunThread(taskGroups[i]); };
    new Thread(t).Start();
}
bool threadsComplete = false;
while(!threadsComplete){
    for(int i=0;i<taskGroups.Count();i++){
        if(threads[i].State == complete)
        threadsComplete = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your `i` variable is shared by all of the threads.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.threadstate.aspx

Comment: In case it's not clear from what Slaks has commented - it would be possible for two (or more) of your threads to start and observe the same value of `i`, when calling `RunThread` - almost certainly something you do not want.

Comment: In addition, if you're learning for future dev work, it would be better to learn to do multi-threading using Tasks and the Task Parallel Library - it's a more up to date set of threading primitives for .NET.

Comment: re the shared i, should I create all of the tasks in one loop, the start all of the tasks in a separate loop?

Comment: @sooprise - if you did that, you'd *guarantee* that they'd all see the same value for `i` - and it would probably be `== taskGroups.Count`, so out of range for the array

Comment: Damien, I just encountered this taskGroup.Count error and I don't know how to fix it. Any suggestions? I'm totally lost...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to store all your threads, and then call Thread.Join().

Something like this:

```
List<Thread> threads = new List<Thread>();
for (int i = 0; i < taskGroups.Count(); i++) {
   int temp = i; //This fixes the issue with i being shared
   Thread thread = new Thread(() => RunThread(taskGroups[temp]));
   threads.Add(thread);
   thread.Start();
}

foreach (var thread in threads) {
    thread.Join();
}
```

Comment: inside of your for loop, how do I assign a method with a parameter to a specific thread? like, thread.doWork=someMethod(aParameter)

Comment: Thread thread = new Thread(() => someMethod(aParameter));  If it complains about your delegate type, cast to a (ThreadStart) inside the Thread constructor.

Comment: I read the guy's comments above. Store "i" in a local variable inside your loop to fix your issue.  I'll update my answer shortly.

Comment: Jonathan, Thanks! that temp variable fixed it up!

Answer (score 1):

If you're using 3.5 then you can [write your own](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1857271/is-there-a-c-equivalent-to-javas-countdownlatch) CountdownEvent, if you're using 4.0 then you can use the built in [CountdownEvent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.countdownevent.aspx) to do something like this:

```
CountdownEvent = new CountdownEvent(taskGroups.Count());

for (int i = 0; i < taskGroups.Count(); i++) 
{
    int item = i; // copy i locally
    ThreadStart t = delegate 
    { 
        RunThread(taskGroups[item]); 
        latch.Signal();
    };
    new Thread(t).Start();
}

latch.Wait();
```

The `latch.Wait()` will cause your code to block until the threads have all finished. Furthermore, you might want to change the way you start your thread a bit:

```
CountdownEvent = new CountdownEvent(taskGroups.Count());

for (int i = 0; i < taskGroups.Count(); i++) 
{
    int item = i; // copy i locally
    Thread t = new Thread(()=>
    { 
        RunThread(taskGroups[item]); 
        latch.Signal();
    });
    t.IsBackground = true;
    t.Start();
}

latch.Wait();
```

Note that I'm setting the thread to background: this your application from hanging when exit and not all threads have finished (i.e. prevents ghost or daemon threads).

Answer (score 0):

You can check the `ThreadState` property of each `Thread` object.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Thread.Join](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/95hbf2ta.aspx) to make sure that each individual thread has finished running.

Answer (score 0):

You can add public static integer field to the main thread, in each child thread increase it by one when it's completed then in the main thread wait (in a loop) until that variable is equal to the `taskGroups.Count()`.

Answer (score 0):

First of all consider switching to the new asynchronous pattern using [`Task`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.aspx).

Anyway if you want to wait for all your threads you can call `Thread.Join`:

```
var threads = new List<Thread>();    
for (int i = 0; i < taskGroups.Count(); i++) {
    ThreadStart t = delegate { RunThread(taskGroups[i]); };
    var thread = new Thread(t);
    threads.Add(thread);
    thread.Start();
}

threads.ForEach(a => a.Join());
```

Remember that you can also pass a timeout parameter that will wait until the thread finishes only if it doesn't takes more than the time you passed in.

Comment: If he's going to switch to using "Task" and .Net 4.0 stuff, why doesn't he just use Parallel.For or Parallel.ForEach?

Comment: Ask him the reason :) I've shown him how to wait for a thread with `Thread` class.